# Troubles with webscraping, selector gadget and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am rather new to webscraping and currently struggling with the table of the following page:

https://www.ggesports.com/en-us/stats/lol/global/Team

I tested scraping text from the website outside the table, this works without a problem, but when I try to scrape a column of the table it only returns the output "character(0)".

I used the selector gadget to identify the specific CSS selector. Afterwards I so far tried:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://www.ggesports.com/en-us/stats/lol/global/Team"
Stats <- read_html(url)


Name <- hot100 %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
  xml2::xml_find_all("//span[contains(@class, 'team-name')]") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()
Name

# and

Name_html <- html_nodes(Stats,'.team-name')
Name <- html_text(Name_html)
Name
```

I would appreciate any help with this.
Thanks anyone in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is pulled dynamically from another endpoint you can find in the network tab. Make your request to that endpoint:

```
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::read_json('https://www.ggesports.com/en-us/stats/lol/global/Team/GetRankingList?season=-1&name=&regionId=50', simplifyVector = T)
```